# Is it possible to force Eclipse to recompile my files every time I try to run JUnit tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

I'd like to know if there's a way to force Eclipse to clear the `bin/` folder of the test that's going to be run, and to recompile all the files again?

I'm asking this as my tests involve deleting/renaming/adding files, and that means that at the moment, only the first run of the test will work ok, as from then on the files on which it works are different from what they were in the beginning.

So, what I am asking is not just to recompile again the .java files in the test folder, but basically to do a local "Clean" on the folder where the test is (I don't want a *FULL* clean/recompilation of the project, as it is *huge*!).

Thanks

Comment: Are any of the files you're manipulating Java class files - or just other resources?

Comment: why can't you manually write an operation for cleaning in the setUp() method of your testcase ?

Comment: Both resource and .class files are having its contents changed. setUp() wouldn't be of much help here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do only a "local clean on the folder where the test is" doesn't seem too likely.

Can't you ensure that all of your files are written to a desired directory - even if to something within File.createTempFile(...) - and then perform a delete on it as part of the beginning of the JUnit test?

Actually, this seems to be exactly what JUnit's TemporaryFolder is for.  Details at http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/09/29/working-temporary-files-junit-47 .  This would also make your build less-specific to Eclipse and work with things like Maven, etc.

Otherwise, just run the test with Ant or Maven - and have it clear out any specific files, folders, or patterns that you need - and then run JUnit.  Both of these integrate nicely into Eclipse, and will meet your needs of completing the task before the program to be tested starts - especially if you will be modifying Java class files as well, which you stated.

Comment: TemporaryFolder seems to be near what I am looking for. But not quite. I'd like it not to delete files AFTER running the tests, but only when I try to run them again (it comes in handy having the test output files at hand..). Anyway, it wouldn't work, as it seems TemporaryFolder is more for resources, and I also need it to apply this process for the .class files themselves!

Comment: How about the Ant or Maven approach?

Comment: They also have their problems. I guess when using ant for running my JUnit tests, they run "outside" Eclipse's Test Results window, right?

Comment: Yes, but you can have it save the test results to an XML file that can be opened up in the same Eclipse UI view once the tests are complete.